# Score for single result from array

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to search phrases in array of elements and get the score for single matching element. Is it possible?

Example scenario

I have two documents:

```
{ names: ["John", "Mathew"] }
```

and now I would like to search John, e.g:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
       "names": { query: "John" }
    }
  }
}
```

and the results should be like that:

```
{
 "_index": "index",
 "_type": "alias",
 "_id": "AVhoV3BinVEjSDmnro5f",
 "_score": 1,
 "_source": {
  "names": [ "John" ]
}
```

Comment: You probably want to investigate the [`nested` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for your use case.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use `fuziness` and `analyzer` in `nested` query?

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: Hmmm, I tried to do this, but I don't know how, do you have some examples? :)

Comment: Show what you've done and we'll go from there

Comment: I tried to use fuziness and analyzer options in this query:
 http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/c0z1lDmkS5 but I don't know how to add to this `fuziness` and `analyzer` option.

Comment: I saw that i can put `analyzer` option in `mapping` but I don't know how to do define `fuziness`. Also would be good to define `fuziness` and `analyzer` options directly in query

Comment: The [`match_phrase`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) documentation shows how to use `analyzer` in the query.

Comment: You might not need a `match_phrase` query though, a `match` could be sufficient. In there you can also specify `"fuzziness": "AUTO"` ([as described here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness))

Comment: I know that I can use match query with `fuziness` and `analyzer` options but I don't know how to use this in nested query or how to doing some `nested` queries in `match` query

Comment: The same query you have in a non-nested context, you can use inside the `query` part of the nested query. Try it out.

Comment: Oh ok, now it's working, thanks guys!